# How multiple join to the same table with other table?

Tags: sql, join

I am not sure of the question title!, but i have this problem

```
 table1 
   id    |  from  |  to
   1         A       B
   2         C       A
   3         B       A

 table2 
   id    |  table1_id
   1         1      
   2         1       
   3         1           
   4         3       
   5         3
   6         2      
   7         2       
   8         2
```

I need to get data from table1 considering rows with ids (2,3) as one row and joined with table2
 fetch the last id between them which is 5
the result

```
   id    |  from     |   to     |   table2_id
   3         B       |    A     |    5
   2         C       |    A     |    8
```

Comment: You show id 1, but id 3's from/to. Is this correct?

Comment: Are 1 and 3 considered the same because they have the same from/to, just reversed?

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Show what you are able to do. Please don't ask us to write your code. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackoverflow homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: @MariaNazari If you notice an inconsistency, don't presume to know what the correct version is & edit, comment to the post owner about it. Your edit should not have been approved.

Comment: Sorry guys, it is a chat system that have two tables `conversation` which has fields `id, from_user, to_user` and `messages` that has `id, conversation_id, text, created_at`, and I am using `codeigniter` so I need `SQL QUERY` to list all conversation of specific user that shows last text message between that user and the others.

Comment: I am half away though, I get this `query`
   `SELECT messages.*, conversation.to_user, conversation.from_user
            FROM messages
            JOIN conversation ON (conversation.id = messages.conversation_id AND (conversation.from_user='.$this->user_id.'  OR conversation.to_user='.$this->user_id.'))
            WHERE messages.id IN (
                        SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM messages
                        GROUP BY conversation_id
                    )
            )`

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned database, I have written SQL in SQL Server

```
WITH TAB_FLAT AS 
(
SELECT TAB_1.table1_id , COALESCE ( TAB_2.table2_id , TAB_1.table2_id ) max_id , TAB_1.table2_id FROM 
( select table1_id , max(id) table2_id from table2 group by table1_id ) TAB_1 
LEFT JOIN  
( select table1_id , max(id) table2_id from table2 group by table1_id ) TAB_2
ON TAB_1.table2_id = TAB_2.table1_id
)
select TAB_FLAT.table1_id AS ID, COALESCE(C.frm ,COALESCE(B.frm,A.frm) ) AS 'FROM' , 
COALESCE(C.to2 ,COALESCE(B.to2,A.to2) ) AS 'TO' , 
TAB_FLAT.max_id AS table2_id
FROM TAB_FLAT 
LEFT JOIN table1 A ON A.id = TAB_FLAT.table1_id
LEFT JOIN table1 B ON B.id = TAB_FLAT.table2_id
LEFT JOIN table1 C ON C.id = TAB_FLAT.max_id
WHERE  TAB_FLAT.table1_id IN (1,2)
```

Demo --> https://rextester.com/DCHUN74655

Explanation:

```
SELECT TAB_1.table1_id , COALESCE ( TAB_2.table2_id , TAB_1.table2_id ) max_id , TAB_1.table2_id FROM 
( select table1_id , max(id) table2_id from table2 group by table1_id ) TAB_1 
LEFT JOIN  
( select table1_id , max(id) table2_id from table2 group by table1_id ) TAB_2
ON TAB_1.table2_id = TAB_2.table1_id
```

We are doing a self left join to get the largest table 2 ID for each table 1 ID
AND corresponding intermediate level.

```
select TAB_FLAT.table1_id AS ID, COALESCE(C.frm ,COALESCE(B.frm,A.frm) ) AS 'FROM' , 
COALESCE(C.to2 ,COALESCE(B.to2,A.to2) ) AS 'TO' , 
TAB_FLAT.max_id AS table2_id
FROM TAB_FLAT 
LEFT JOIN table1 A ON A.id = TAB_FLAT.table1_id
LEFT JOIN table1 B ON B.id = TAB_FLAT.table2_id
LEFT JOIN table1 C ON C.id = TAB_FLAT.max_id
```

We are joining to table 1 based on table1 id , intermediate id and largest  id

```
WHERE  TAB_FLAT.table1_id IN (1,2)
```

Filtering out records with ID = 1 or 2

Answer (score -1):

First, write a query to get each row's max ID in table 2.

```
select t1.*, max(t2.id) as table2_id
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
group by t1.id
```

Then use that as a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) for two queries. One to get all the rows *except* 1 and 3. And one to get 1 or 3, whichever has a greater table2_id. [`union`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) them together.

```
with max_table2 as (
  select t1.*, max(t2.id) as table2_id
  from table2 t2
  join table1 t1 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
  group by t1.id
)
select *
from max_table2
where id not in (1,3)
union
(
  select *
  from max_table2
  where id in (1,3)
  order by table2_id desc
  limit 1
)
```

If the combined 1/3 row *must* have the ID of 1, despite 3 having the larger table2_id, this can be done by hard coding the ID in the select query.

```
with max_table2 as (
  select t1.*, max(t2.id) as table2_id
  from table2 t2
  join table1 t1 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
  group by t1.id
)
select *
from max_table2
where id not in (1,3)
union
(
  select 1 as id, "from", "to", table2_id
  from max_table2
  where id in (1,3)
  order by table2_id desc
  limit 1
)
```

[Try it.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=eaca54096a989830aa1609e52d70b9c9)

---

I suspect rather than hard coding rows 1 and 3, you're actually counting them as equivalent because they have the same path, just reversed. We can make this query more generic.

First, normalize the from/to so they're in the same order. While we're at it, also get their max table2 id.

```
select
  t1.id,
  case when "from" < "to" then "from" else "to" end as "from",
  case when "from" < "to" then "to" else "from" end as "to",
  max(t2.id) as max_table2_id
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
group by t1.id


id  from    to  max_table2_id
2   A       C   8
3   A       B   5
1   A       B   3
```

Then rank the paths with the same from/to.

```
with normalized_max_table2 as (
select
  t1.id,
  case when "from" < "to" then "from" else "to" end as "from",
  case when "from" < "to" then "to" else "from" end as "to",
  max(t2.id) as table2_id
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
group by t1.id
)
select *,
  rank() over (partition by "from", "to" order by table2_id desc) as "rank"
from normalized_max_table2


id  from    to  table2_id   rank
3   A       B   5           1
1   A       B   3           2
2   A       C   8           1
```

And, finally, select only the first ranks.

```
with normalized_max_table2 as (
select
  t1.id,
  case when "from" < "to" then "from" else "to" end as "from",
  case when "from" < "to" then "to" else "from" end as "to",
  max(t2.id) as table2_id
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
group by t1.id
),
ranked_max_table2 as (
  select *,
    rank() over (partition by "from", "to" order by table2_id desc) as "rank"
  from normalized_max_table2
)
select id, "from", "to", table2_id
from ranked_max_table2
where "rank" = 1


id  from    to  table2_id
3   A       B   5
2   A       C   8
```

That's a long-hand way of doing it. There may be a more compact way.

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c56d19a1931369a7c1df37c46c039d36).